# Why the cube is white shiny color in the regular scene in the editor but when loading the scene the cube is gray darker?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the original Game scene the cube is white :

[image: cube settings in the game scene before running the game]

and this screenshot is of the directional lightning in the same Game scene :

[image: directional lightning settings]

Then this is the same scene with the same cube settings and directional lightning settings after i loaded the scene from another scene by pressing a button :

[image: cube settings]

and the directional lightning. to make the cube white again i need to change the directional lightning intensity value from 1 to something higher.

[image: directional lightning settings]

If every object settings are the same camera , directional light and the cube why when loading the scene from another scene the cube is not white and i need to change the intensity value ?

Maybe because in the scene i'm loading the Game scene from the main camera Clear Flags is setting to Solid Color and also the Background is not the same as in the Game scene ? but why is that will make any changes when loading the Game scene ? I'm not sure what is going on. also when i'm loading only the Game scene and running the game only with the Game scene everything is fine with the cube only when loading the scene from the other scene then this cube change happens.

Answer (score 0):

When render pipeline you're using?
If it is URP, you have to set it to lit version of the shader if you want it to be lit by the light present in scene. If you decide to set it o unlit, it remain the same in all cases.